# Is it possible to show toast notification on lockscreen in windows 8.1 store app

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps

I know we can show badge images on lockscreens, but can toast notifications be shown when screen is locked using windows store javascript app?

Comment: Yes, it is possible :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Toasts automatically appear on the lock screen for lock screen-enabled apps (not for all apps, however). Here's a quote from the [Toast notification overview docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779727.aspx#showing_toast_on_the_lock_screen):

> Toast associated with an app that has a tile or badge on the lock
>   screen will also appear on the lock screen. Toast shown on the lock
>   screen is identical to toast shown elsewhere. It differs in that all
>   toasts on the lock screen are shown for the length of a long-duration
>   toast. For more information, see the [Lock screen overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh779720.aspx).

If you are lock-screen enabled, then sending toasts in the usual way will surface them on the lock screen. See [Quickstart: sending a toast notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465448.aspx).